# bluetooth pairing fails everytime i connect to other devices

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

i installed the driver as illustrated by answer on this link 
[Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

By doing so, it enabled my bluetooth.I can search other devices, other devices can detect mine.
But now the problem is that i can't pair with any of other devices.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue with bluetooth devices so far from what i have gathered by piecing forums together is that some how some way pulse audio for some reason errors out and shuts down..

I have successfully gotten my bluetooth headset working but it hasnt been any fun... I too couldnot use bluetooth to transfer files until i did some of the following not sure exactly what worked either..

sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-tools bluez-utils

sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

This article here was also some what helpfull too sorry for not having a direct answer but i too at times have issues with bluetooth and has resulted in multiple reinstalls I am currently running Ubuntu Studio 14.04
[Pulseaudio not detecting bluetooth headset automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically)