# Adding Bluetooth Devices Ubuntu 15.10 64bit

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10, intel-wireless, bluetooth-speaker

When I Bluetooth -> Device Search:

**I can see the device** (a bluetooth headset named 'Music Receiver')

When I add the device, it just comes back and says **"Setting up 'Music Receiver' failed**.

Nothing appears in syslog, when I try this.

Please advise on where one even goes, to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulseaudio not detecting bluetooth headset automatically](http://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I was able to connect my device using "Bluetooth Manager" once I installed the "blueman" package,
whereas I was previously unsuccessful trying to connect my device using the "bluetooth" icon on the menu bar...