# Issues with bluetooth-module-discover

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am not able to use my Bluetooth headsets post I switch from ubuntu 22.04 to ubuntu 22.10. They connect alright but the system does not use them as the output device. In fact, the headsets are not available as output devices available.

I dug around and discovered that the issue is mainly with `module-bluetooth-discover`.

My issues are that:

1. `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` results in `Connection failure: Connection refused pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`
2. I cannot implement the solution provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically?noredirect=1&lq=1) since I am using ubuntu 22.10 and wyland `/etc/pulse/default.pa` does not contain `if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null fi` codebit

How can I get my `module-bluetooth-discover` working properly?